# Set up a database to import large amounts of data

Tags: mysql, database, import, etl

I am new to databases and programming and am now supposed to create a database that can store large amounts of data. The critical problem to me is that i need to update the database everyday and add 150 sets of data to 60 different tables. The datasets all come in a different format though (.csv, .row, .sta...).

I would like to be able to create an automatical import and update the tables daily.

Does someone have a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what your require can be done using crons.

[Take a look at this][1]http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

This will help you to run the program automatically for time period.

Comment: Thank you! My first impression though is that it will only work with Linux or mac. I use Microsoft though... am I wrong?